# weak square and tower forcing

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

Suppose $\delta$ is a Woodin cardinal and $\kappa < \delta$.  If $G$ is generic for the stationary tower $\mathbb Q^\kappa_{<\delta}$, then there is an elementary embedding $j : V \to M \subseteq V[G]$, with $j(\kappa^+) = \delta$ and $M^{<\delta} \cap V[G] \subseteq M$. [Reference here.](http://www.users.miamioh.edu/larsonpb/toronto_tower.pdf)

Suppose $\square_{\kappa,\lambda}$ fails in $V$, where $\lambda \leq \kappa$.  Does it fail in $V[G]$?

Comment: Very nice question!

Comment: If $\kappa$ is a successor cardinal and $\lambda = \kappa$ then in order to get that weak square on $\kappa$ still fails in $V[G]$ we have to require that $(2^\kappa)^{V[G]} > (\kappa^+)^{V[G]} = \delta$, which looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: @Yair, you're right about this being suspicious.  A counting argument shows that $\delta^+$ is a fixed point of the embedding, so in $M$ there is a bijection between $(2^\kappa)^M = (2^\kappa)^{V[G]}$ and some ordinal $<j(\delta)<\delta^+$.  But maybe $\kappa = \omega_1$, and it is consistent to have $2^{\omega_1} = \omega_2$ with no special $\omega_2$-trees.

Comment: We can start with $\delta$ Woodin but not weakly compact, so there may be a disagreement between $M$ and $V[G]$ about whether there is a $\delta$-Aronszajn tree.  Is it possible to have some version of a "special" $\delta$-tree, which will turn into the ordinary kind of special tree when $\delta$ becomes a successor?

Comment: I see, so simple counting arguments don't rule out even the possibility $\kappa = \omega_1$. The cardinals in my remark were off-by-one...

Comment: Another remark: We can avoid using the embedding to compute $(2^\kappa)^{V[G]}$.  Since the tower is $\delta$-presaturated, every name for a subset of $\kappa$ is forced to have the same evaluation as a name of size $<\delta$.